# Init NSMutableArray of class object

Tags: objective-c, swift

I work with both Objective C / Swift class in my project and I have this problem :

I try to init an NSMutableArray which contains objects of type XXXIndicator in Swift according to my objective C method which is :

```
- (void)myMethod : (NSMutableArray<XXXIndicator*> *) indicatorsArray;
```

I create my Swift mutable array like that :

```
var indicatorsArrayCABarDatasource = [XXXIndicator]()
```

It works fine for now.

And when I call my objective-c method (which has been generated to a swift method by my bridging class), I get the following error :

```
"Cannot convert value of type [XXXIndicator] to expected argument type "NSMutableArray!"
```

How I call my method :

```
myView.myMethod(indicatorsArrayCABarDatasource)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Swift arrays, even if they are declared with `var`, are bridged to `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray`, so you have to explicitly convert it to an `NSMutableArray` with its contructor, like:

```
NSMutableArray(array: indicatorsArrayCABarDatasource)
```

Comment: Thank you it works. Yes I just noticed that my generated method in swift was :     `public func createWithPercentBarWithArrayOfIndicators(indicatorsArray: NSMutableArray!)`